# Android Alarm Scheduling with repeats

Tags: java, android, api, android-alarms, android-jobscheduler

I am in need of creating an app with "reminding" facility. For an example, user can set a reminder for "Jogging" and he can do following when setting up this reminder. Below is the normal process.

1. User setup the reminder with "cause" to be reminded (ex: jogging )
2. User can set the reminder to fire at 10am Monday, and so on.
3. If required, user can set the alarm for multiple days (ex: Monday, Tuesday, Friday )
4. user can set the reminders to be repeated. (Ex: "Every Monday at 10am". Ie else "Every Monday, Tuesday, Sunday at 10am ")
5. User can set any number of reminders for various causes.
6. At the time of reminder, the user will get a notification in his phone.
7. After setting the reminder, entire process will run in background.

I was trying to find a better way to do this, this is basically like an alarm application. I looked into 'AlarmManager' , 'JobScheduler' and so on, nothing seems to match what I want to do, the correct alarm set-up and repeated reminders when set.

I looked into some alarm app examples too, seems too complicated when my core app is not an "alarm" app.

What is the exact library of doing this? I am not creating an alarm app, this is a process required for another app we build.

Comment: It seems like `AlarmManager` is what you would want here.. what about it would not work?

Comment: @nick friskel: how would you ask it to repeat? I am looking to make my work east as possible.

Comment: You would set up a `Calendar` object to use as your `AlarmManager` start time.  If it would not be a set interval, then you would have it set up to where it made a new alarm after one goes off to re-set it.  It will not be very simple to configure but `AlarmManager` will likely be your only way of doing it correctly.